# Remove item from "Android Private Libraries" grayed out. Cannot remove jar

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

I have an Eclipse project and I am trying to update a library into a newer Jar file.

However the Eclipse Project will not let me remove the old library?

I closed eclipse and attempted to just manually delete it from the folder and reboot eclipse but it still won't let me compile now because the old "jar file is missing"

Any ideas?

image update:

[image]

Comment: did u removed from lib?

Comment: That's what I am saying, I can't remove it from the list. It's grayed out. I tried manually removing it in the windows folder but it still appears after relaunching eclipse.

Comment: m saying properties windows? ur windiws shown in question isnt properties

Comment: This is literally what I am trying to do and cannot.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question and the following solution works for me.

1. In the `Order and Export` tab, cancel the checkbox of `Android Private Libraries` and click OK to save.
2. Re-open this property page and you will find the old library is updated.

I don't know if it is just a bug in Eclipse. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Delete the library .jar from the /libs folder

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new project without that jar and merge all code and resources of project this is an alternative

Answer (score 0):

I just choice i want delete .jar at the "libs" folder , then delete it ,then it will auto disappear at Android Private Libraries

Answer (score 0):

try to delete the library manually. **C:/eclipse/plugins/somewhere.jar**

Here are are all the libraries of eclipse(android,and everything extra like jar files)

The problem is that when you have two libraries version (3.4 and 3.7.6) for example they have some same files that cause **dublicate entries** and more unexpected errors.