# Remove library from android project / "Found duplicate file" error

Tags: java, android, libraries

As first information: I use Eclipse (Luna).

Some time ago, I added the "Jackson" libraries to my android project, to do some json mapping. However, I recently moved many of my backend classes into a seperate, plain java project and included Jackson there. This plain java project has then been added as required project in the android project's build path.

When I try to launch my app, I receive the following error:

```
[2015-02-10 16:17:37 - 46 - Android] Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: allclasses-frame.html
Origin 1: Z:\Jackson (JSON Processing)\jackson-core-2.4.2-javadoc.jar
Origin 2: Z:\Jackson (JSON Processing)\jackson-databind-2.4.2-javadoc.jar
```

However, I do not believe this is the real error, because the same .jar files work without problems in other projects. I think that I may have missed something when I was removing the jars from the android project and adding the new project dependency.

I just deleted the files in the libs directory of the android project, but this did not work. Then, I tried [the answer from Bryce (#2) to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077689/remove-item-from-android-private-libraries-grayed-out-cannot-remove-jar). I have the same problem, that I cannot remove the jars from the "Android Private Libraries" because it is grayed out. This solution worked and I was happy, but when I restarted Eclipse, I had the same problem again. So I can solve it, but only until the next restart of Eclipse. I have reproduced this several times, but I have no clue what to do now. Has anybody a idea how to solve this problem on a permanent base?

Comment: The problem with Eclipse is that it's literally collapsing on top of itself. It has gotten so bad with Luna, that we had to reinstall it several times just to fix such simple issues. I wouldn't recommend that as a way of solving your problem, but it seems to be the only reliable solution, that we've found in the office.

Comment: you have this problem when you want to export your project as an apk?

Comment: @crAlex When I solve the problem temporarily, as described above, I can export the apk and it works as expected. However, I cannot export it before I use the workaround. Eclipse shows a message that there are errors in my code and it cannot build the apk file.

Comment: look i had a similar problem with exporting a .jar i had doublicate entry like your that's because those libraries i added to project(was more that 7) had a file security.class two times.The most crazy is to decomplile the library contain one of this files and change name(ok is too lazy..), me just exported the jar with the libraries to other folder(so no problem) but for android project i am not sure if you have that option..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution!
Well, it is still more like a workaround, but it works at least.

To be honest, it is so simple that it took me some time to think about it:
I use git as a version control tool. So I did the following: I solved the problem temporarily, as described above, and made a commit via git. Then I made a backup of the git folder which I did not need, but just in case... I removed the project from Eclipse via the "Delete" function, **without** removing the project data from the hard disk. After a restart of Eclipse, I reimported the project from the git directory. That seems to have solved my problem. I did some restarts of Eclipse, and it still works.